# in_array() function doesn't work properly

Tags: php, oop

I got a task to make a representation of 5 HTML elements in OOP so I started but in constructor I've already had a problem. I don't know what is wrong with this. The problem is function in_array() doesn't work properly.

htmlTags.php

```
<?php

   class htmlTags
   {
       public $tags = array('a', 'img', 'div', 'input', 'select');
       public $tag;
       public $num;

       function __construct($control)
       {
¨         if (in_array($control, $tags))
          {
            $this->num = 1;  
          }   
          else
          {
             $this->num = 0;  
          }
       }
   }
```

index.php

```
<?php
  require_once('classes/htmlTags.php');

  $tag = new htmlTags('a');
  echo $tag->num;
 ?>
```

Although "a" exists in array $tags, everytime I get a echo "0" which should mean it doesn't exist in array.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: you mean `$this->tags`, `$tags` doesn't exists in the constructor. If you enable your `display_errors` you will see a notice.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right.